# How do I set a user profile pic in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

I simply want to get an image in gnome like this one:

[image: help center]

And here is how mine looks like:

[image: mine]

To clarify, I want to add my name near the arrow as above and when I click on it I want to get an image I choose. Like the image above of "wanda".

So how can I set an image like this?

Comment: TO set the picture, go to Users section in Settings. Next to your name will be a blank box. Click on it and select a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings and then User Accounts, the image is set there.

Comment: Can we use a gif?